# Why after installing PyQT5 the module QTCore is missing in anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

EveryTime i execute this code it gives me ModuleNotFoundError.I am using spyder IDE.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QTCore'

I tried using updating conda.But didn't work.How to fix this module?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton,QMainWindow,QApplication
import sys
from PyQt5.QTCore import QRect
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try QtCore, with a little t :-) .